Sock pairing game for Android
I am looking for an Android application that allows you to move around washed and dried socks and pair them, after going through them.
Thank you for your contribution.

So you are looking for a game? Because for "move around washed and dried socks" you would need a robot.

It's much funnier to do that in real life. Socks on the phone are missing the haptic and olfactory feedback. You know, you should sort those socks in need of a wash from those which are already washed.

But why? I assume to teach a kid or something, but isn't that best done on real examples?
